# how does single supply op-amp work while its non-inverting input is connected to ground?

Tags: analog, opto-isolator, photodiode, single-supply-op-amp

In [HCNR200 Datasheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AV02-0886EN), the page 11, figure 13-A, there is a sample that confused me.
In this sample, the Vin is applied to the inverting input and if the electric current passes through PD1, PD1 voltage goes to zero and finally when PD1 voltage reached to zero, the voltage on inverting input is around zero, but a bit more than non-inverting input voltage.
So, how does op-amp output go to higher than zero and adjust the current of LED?
And for right side op-amp, how does op-amp output go to more than zero while its non-inverting input is connected to ground and inverting input is going to higher than it?

*Op-Amps are powered by a single supply.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to eesx. Can you post a picture of the figure you are referring to? Is it [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA8tA.png)? I found no trace of PD1, can you clarify?

Comment: please check out this:https: //www.edn.com/Home/PrintView?contentItemId=4458406

Comment: Figure 13-A isn't on page 11 and it doesn't have a part labelled PD1. Please edit your question to include the actual circuit you're asking about without relying on links to external sites otherwise it's likely to be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1):

I've copied the relevant figure from the data sheet so that I can speak to it.

The HCNR200 couples the LED output equally to the photodiodes.  So assuming good matching, the current induced on the photodiodes is equal if their voltages are equal.

A photodiode is a current *generator*, so it will drive its cathode negative when light is shined on it.  So in the circuit to the left, \$V_{IN}\$ tends to drive the op-amp positive input high, which lights the LED.  This generates a current in PD1 which drives its cathode voltage **down**.  Assuming stability (which you'll find to be a big assumption when you try to make this work), A1 will hold the LED current to whatever it needs to be so that \$V_{IN} - I_{PD1} R1 = 0\$.

This will induce a current in PD2.  Again, the cathode of PD2 will tend to be driven *more negative* than its anode.  A2 will counteract this by raising \$V_{OUT}\$.  If PD1 and PD2 are nicely matched, then \$V_{OUT}\$ will be proportional to \$V_{IN}\$.

[image]

Comment: That is Ok, but how does PD1 go to negative while Vin is positive? Suppose that PD1 is short circuit, so it can not goes to negative!!

Comment: @MohammadHussainAsadzadeh, the photodiode can turn the light energy hitting it into electrical energy, so it can operate in the II and IV quadrants. Another way of saying this is, it doesn't act like a short circuit, it acts like a current source.

Comment: Thank you so much. i got it that the photodiode is modeled by a current source ( https://www.thorlabs.com/tutorials.cfm?tabID=31760 ), But i still do not understand how the voltage on the inverting input becomes negative?

Comment: If current from the Photodiode pulls down (goes INTO) the photodiode.

Comment: I mean, what is the mechanism of negative voltage at that point?  it is my problem that the positive input should be larger than the negative input until output is positive(larger than zero)!

Comment: @MohammadHussainAsadzadeh - The photodiode is operating in a mode referred to as Photovoltaic - it actually generates a current (in the same fashion as a solar cell)  That tries to make the input of the opamp go negative but the feedback through the resistor keeps the voltage close to zero (it could be slightly positive or negative depending upon the offset voltage of the opamp). No negative power supply is required.

Comment: @MohammadHussainAsadzadeh - A photodiode is not like a resistor or transistor. It is, in fact, a generator. It produces voltage (and current) without any applied voltage. Light which is absorbed by the PD physically knocks electrons loose from the material which accumulate at one terminal. And, for what it's worth, ignoring offset voltages in the op amp, the + input never goes negative. It just gets closer to zero than it would if there were no PD. The proof of this is that the LED current is positive, which means the output voltage is positive, and this can only occur if the + input is pos.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Ok, but, why did i say negative voltage? Because when you have an OP-AMP, for make its output to high, you should apply a +voltage on its input. But this +voltage is ( V+  minus V-), which means +input minus -input. So if i have +voltage on its output, This means that i have +voltage on input that means i have a voltage on +input that it is greater than -input. Is that right? if it is right, it means that the PD voltage gets closer to zero(ground) but a bit smaller than +input(ground). Is my argument correct?

Comment: @MohammadHussainAsadzadeh - I *was* talking about the left circuit, the one with the LED. I assume that you are now  talking about the right circuit. And in the right circuit, the + input is connected directly to ground, which means that for a positive output the - input must be negative. But I bet that you think the op amps is powered by a single + voltage, right? Nope. The circuit as shown will not work with a single, positive supply. It must have both + and - voltages on its supply pins.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Common mode on an LM358 goes to -VCC; it probably works enough below that to make the circuit work.  Running it on dual supplies would be smarter, though.  I wouldn't be surprised if there were parts out there that are specified to go slightly below the - input voltage.